# Aspire A514-55 Bluetooth not working properly

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, acer

When i received my laptop which is a Acer Aspire A514-55 and installed Ubuntu 22.04 on it I noticed quite early that something is not working properly with Bluetooth. When i turn it on the Settings panel nothing happens. I checked if the laptop could detect the Bluetooth adapter, and yes it did (with this command sudo lsusb | grep Bluetooth. I also checked with systemctl if its on and yes it is (hciconfig and sudo service bluetooth status). Also tried to restart it.

I started scrolling around the internet and Stack Overflow for solutions but nothing seem to work for my laptop. I'm starting to wonder if the drivers for my Bluetooth adapter doesn't work or exist in Ubuntu. I feel quite confident in Ubuntu and doesn't really wanna change distro.

Also. here's some system information from CLI:

```
System Information
        Manufacturer: Acer
        Product Name: Aspire A514-55
        Version: V1.04
        Serial Number: NXK5DED0082211DB213400
        UUID: 25050265-3fd7-ec11-80e5-088fc3607b83
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: 0000000000000000
        Family: Aspire 5
```

Theres no "Turn on Bluetooth" button either in the quick panel (where you can quickly choose e.g. wifi).

If there is some information missing which you require, feel free to ask me about it. Thanks in advance!